# How test function in window?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing

```
class CTest : public CWindowImpl<CTest>
{
public:
  CTest();
  ~CTest();

  BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(CTest)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE, OnClose)
    ...
    CROSS_PROCESS_HANDLER(WM_HTTP_REQUEST_DATA, OnRequest)
  END_MSG_MAP()

  ...
};

class CTestXYZ : public CWindowImpl<CTestXYZ>
{
    // Accept DOWNLOAD_DATA Message 
    CROSS_PROCESS_HANDLER(WM_DOWNLOAD_DATA, OnDownload)
};

class CTestResponse : public CWindowImpl<CTestRes>
{
    // Accept DOWNLOAD_DATA_RESPONSE Message
    CROSS_PROCESS_HANDLER(DOWNLOAD_DATA_RESPONSE , OnResponse) 
};
```

First, I send message `WM_HTTP_REQUEST_DATA` to window `CTest` and execute function `OnRequest`;

Second, the function `OnRequest` will send message `WM_DOWNLOAD_DATA` to window `CTestXYZ` and ececute function `OnDownload` in other process;

Third, the function `OnDownload` download data and return it, and the function sends `DOWNLOAD_DATA_RESPONSE` to window `CTestResponse`, the function `OnResponse` will accept data.

**Now, I need test the function `OnRequest` in according to the function `OnResponse`, so I want to use other function replace `OnResponse`.**

**So, how do I ? Thanks!**